# What should the 404 image be for the site?

Tags: discussion, site-attributes, top-7

(Spun off of [Site Attributes](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41/site-attributes).)

Ideas for the 404 image? Should it be funny (in context) like the StackOverflow ones are? Should it be dead serious?

Please include image links, if possible.

One image per answer, please, so the highest-voted bubbles to the top for official review.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just wanted to say the 404 image the site is currently using (presumably designed by Jin) is pretty awesome:

[image: Quick, which way to the fairy fountain??]

Answer (score 41):

Am I the only one that likes it exactly how it is in the beta?

[image: 404 - may your page is another castle]

Comment: I +1ed. But the discussion was supposed to get a spin-off ... (And I'd rather see it in color, though Nintendo might have a hissy fit.)

Comment: Yes I'm aware.. just seeing if anyone noticed the awesome beta 404 page @Dr.

Comment: I hadn't until you posted this. :)

Comment: +1 for a full color, screenshot-ish version.

Comment: The new image is pretty cool (in keeping with the "sketch" theme of the beta sites), but totally off for a gaming-specific site ... Yes, the prior one was rock-hard awesome and I hope can be recovered.

Comment: It was still in my cache - I hope I'm not getting into trouble for reposting it...

Comment: @JonB: I've posted a full-color, screenshot-ish version too

Answer (score 16):

It's a quick job, but...

[Base image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rhz5.gif), if some different text arrangement is preferred (or even just the original).

[image]

Comment: Epic; I love it.

Answer (score 15):

I love this concept:

[image: Tetris]

Obviously it would be cleaned up on the real site.

Answer (score 14):

Well this is a less sketch-like take on the image we already have:

[image]

**Fun fact**: The actual copy is "Our princess is in another castle", but most of us remember it as "**Y**our princess is in another castle."

Comment: It *really* isn't "**Y**our princess..."? Damn my memory!

Comment: But you should finish the castle with Mushroom- or Flower-Mario :p

Answer (score 11):

[image: the cake is a lie]

*source: http://hurtlingthruspace.wordpress.com/2009/05/05/the-cnc-music-factory-is-still-alive/*

Comment: Love it! ` ` ` `

Comment: Would be awesome, but are you sure that's not copyrighted by someone?

Comment: @Oak there's plenty of similar ascii arts, e.g. [this](http://frijole.livejournal.com/503388.html) and [that](http://www.codeismylife.com/ascii_the_cake_11_its_a_lie/33794.html), so it should be possible to find one that isn't copyrighted

Answer (score 6):

> ## Page Not Found
>
> We're sorry, we couldn't find the page you requested. However, we did find the release date for Half Life Two, Episode Three:
>
> [image: Six to eight weeks.]

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19514#19514

Comment: too bad it is less applicable now, seeing the recent development.

Comment: @alexander Fixed. We should be okay for a valve year or so now :P

Answer (score 5):

Battlezone, anyone?

[image: Game Over]

Answer (score 4):

The obvious, but it may be too small:

[image: All your bases are belong to us]

Also, probably played out. Really played out?

Comment: I was thinking about that, but perhaps "All your pages are belong to us" :P

Comment: "Really played out?" that would be my opinion...

Answer (score 4):

I like ZorboTHut's [idea at meta.gamedev](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180/404-page-not-found-image-nominations/182#182):

> I'm going to guess we might not have the bandwidth for a little Flash or HTML5 game.
>
> But we really should have a little Flash or HTML5 game. How awesome would that be?

Comment: http://google.com/pacman

Answer (score -3):

The 404 page shouldn't have 404 anywhere on it.  It should be [helpful](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/creating-user-friendly-404-pages.html) to people that can't find something they are looking for.

Comment: Have a look at Stack Overflow. That's what we're trying to do here. Have something helpful on the left, funny on the right.

Comment: Also, IMO every 404 page should say "404." In an ideal world, no user would see HTTP codes, but due to how the web developed, most people instantly understand what 404 means, and that association should be used when designing 404 pages.